# When do side effects happen?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I'm building an app with blocking HTTP calls. I'd like to print something before the block and then continue with something after the blocking call is done. My first tought was to do it like this

```
(print "Processing " item-hash "...")
(query-item item-hash)
(Thread/sleep 10000)
(println "Done")))
```

Sleep is there just to slow it down even more to be 100% sure it does what it's supposed to.

In my understanding, it should print the message, start `query-item`, then sleep for 10 seconds and print `Done` after that. But currently it waits until the entire parent sexpr is done and prints after that (prints the entire line when all blocking calls are done.

Entire main for reference

```
(defn -main [& echo]
  (map
    (fn [url]
      (let [item-hash (market-listing-url-to-hash-name url)]
        (print "Processing " item-hash "...")
        (query-item item-hash)
        (Thread/sleep 10000)
        (println "Done")))

    (collect-urls 1)))
```

Thanks

Comment: Why does slowing things down make you sure it does what it's supposed to do? Also, map is lazy and did you want pmap?

Comment: The query-item is fast now so I wasn't entirely sure if it prints "Processing ..." first and "Done" after that. Thanks for suggesting pmap but I can't do it in parallel. `query-item` is hitting 3rd party HTTP API that allows only few requests per second. After a little poking around I found out that if I do (println) instead of (print), it works as expected. The output buffer probably flushes on newline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearently `print` doesn't automatically flush the buffer to the screen. Adding `(flush)` after the first `print` fixes it. `println` flushes it itself.

source code: [println](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3451) calls `prn` function that has `(flush)` as one of the side effects [prn](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.6.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3440)